# How to configure my TL-WR741N to forward DNS from my Chromecast to Unblock-US DNS servers

Tags: router, dns, port-forwarding, chromecast

I am looking for help.  I live in Czech Republic and am currently subscribed to Netflix by using www.unblock-us.com.

I have now acquired a Chromecast, however I am unable to use it with Netflix as the Chromecast has the Google DNS servers hardcoded into it.

I have read that it is possible to make to changes to your server so that the Google servers are bypassed and you can use for example in my case the unblock-us servers.

I have tried to access my router using telnet but port 23 is blocked.

I am able to log into the router via my browser but I have no idea how to make these changes.

Comment: Why not just set DNS manually in your desktops/laptops?

Comment: It is not a solution to your problem, but it is a solution to the Netflix problem: have you looked at Hola Unblocker? When you load the Netflix page, wait about 15 seconds for it to work.

Comment: Hi @MariusMatutiae thanks for this.  I am able to do this and actually have the DNS settings configured at router level.  I really want to be able to cast the netflix to my TV as oposed to using cable though.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your router to use whatever DNS server you like, but if your Chromecast has hardcoded DNS servers (probably 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4), it won't even ask your router for DNS info and will continue to resolve to wherever its DNS server tells it to.

You can capture any internal DNS traffic from your chromecast and redirect it to the unblock-us servers but most routers won't support this functionality, I know mine doesn't.

[DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) is a router firmware that you can install and will perform what you are trying to achieve. It is not overly difficult to install but must be careful and you run the risk of bricking your router. If you go down this road I recommend you read all the DD-WRT documentation related to your router carefully before installing anything.

Comment: Hi Chris,  many thanks for this information.  I will take a look into this and if I am comfortable with it I will give a go.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [the instruction](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2435579) here, but before that, make sure that your device supports dd-wrt.

I was in the exactly same situation as you, and I had to get a new router, and installed tomato firmware before I could do the configuration, and even so, [the router was unstable](https://superuser.com/q/674774/522).

Comment: @pclegg1977, glad to hear your compliment.. as a small favor, would you like to upvote ( and/or accept) my answer? This is how the community here expresses the value of an answer